# My webhosting won't allow "Options" in .htaccess

Tags: 7, .htaccess

My webhosting provider of 4 years said they don't allow "Options" in .htaccess files. They were referring to lines 11 and 14 of the .htaccess file. Is it ok to comment these out?

These lines are

```
# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Does it pose a security risk?

Comment: What do the lines 11 and 14 of the .htaccess file say?

Comment: Find a new provider, seriously.

Comment: What hosting do you suggest?

Comment: http://drupal.org/hosting has a number of them. Really, any modern webhost will allow these. But you'll never be happy with any nontrivial site using shared hosting... so start thinking about a VPS.

Comment: I'm thinking of going for bluehost based on drupal.org/hosting. I'll probably buy it at the end of the week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Options -Indexes` prevents users from seeing which files exist in a directory. You shouldn't use this feature to secure your site, it mainly exists for aesthetic reasons. It is technically never necessary.

`Options +FollowSymLinks` is not necessary in a vanilla Drupal installation, chances are you do not need this one either.

Have a look at the [documentation of the Options directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#options) for more details.